# How to use shared preferences to update data from another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two activities A and B. A is the homepage and when the plus button is clicked it goes to B where there are two edit texts (question and answer). When both are inputted it and the check button is clicked, it is taken back to A where a new button appears with the text set to the inputted question. I have an inflated view which allows the user to edit the question and answer when clicking the button. The problem is that when I use finish() on activity B, it destroys it. I want to use shared preferences on activity A to save the inputted texts on question B but I have no idea how. Can anyone please help?

Activity A:

```
    package com.example.uh

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val question = preferences.getString("text", "")
        val answer = preferences.getString("text2", "")
        if (question != null && answer != null) {
        //?
        }
        else{
        //?
        }

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
                    with(builder) {
                        setTitle(newbutton.text)
                        setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                            Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                        }
                        setView(dialogLayout)
                        show()
                    }
        }
    }}
```

Activity B:

```
    package com.example.uh

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()
            val answertext = answer.text.toString()
            val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString("text", questiontext)
            editor.putString("text2", answertext)
            editor.apply()


            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you send the data to the second activity with the intent?

Comment: Can you be more elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Right after your `sharedPreferences` line, you can use it to set the initial text of the two views and have it default to an empty String if nothing has been set yet (e.g. the first time the second Activity is opened).

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
question.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("text", ""))
answer.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("text2", ""))
```

Comment: oh my god i cant thank you enough it was that simple. i was trying so many different methods. the only slight problem i have is that when i go to make another button (if i already made one) it automatically is set to the previous text i inputted. I want it to be empty. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @CinnamonToastCrunch12 I'm not sure what are you doing but I'm sure this is not right way to do it. Sending data to another activity should be done using Intent object

Comment: @bakero98 well i did try to use intents but it wasnt working that well for me so i just used sharedPreferences which seem to be going fine now. it's only that slight problem i have that i outlined in the above comment

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. If you want the question and answer text to persist between app sessions, SharedPreferences is the right way to do it. But as to your follow-up question, this becomes more tricky because you need to store an arbitrary number of pairs of question and answer. That is better suited for a database, which is a big topic to learn.

Comment: well the problem that im actually having now is that my text data is not actually being saved to each individual button but rather the last inputted text

Comment: @bakero98 would intent fix this problem? Im trying to save each individually inputted text to each created dynamic button. or do i have to make a database?

Comment: This still could be done with SharedPreferences, by using an appended number on the string keys of your preference values. So each pair of values would have a unique pair of keys. Your Activity A would need some way of remembering which button goes with which number, maybe by adding it as a tag when you create the button. And then pass that number in the Intent for Activity B. But you're not supposed to store a large amount of data with SharedPreferences. I think you're limited to 1MB. Anyway, this is a large number of steps to explain. I don't have time right now.